# setting the boolean with the Timer on android

Tags: android, timer

I would like to have a timer that goes for like 20 seconds and at every 5 sec which could change the boolean from false to true and it could reset in other second. 
for instance

```
Timer t = new Timer(20);
from seconds 1 - 4 : boolean false
second 5 : boolean true
```

Comment: Is the solution really working? I think you need to modify it.

Comment: @AnuragSingh yeah i can set the boolean in the onTick function and i reset it to false on the function where the true condition was called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new CountDownTimer(20000, 5000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

     }

     public void onFinish() {
         //your code here for setting the boolean
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: I think your comment should be in the top box for setting the boolean.

Answer (score 1):

```
new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
        Log.d(TAG, "onTick:: seconds="+seconds);
        if ((seconds % 5) == 0) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onTick:: 5 seconds lap");
          //set your boolean variable to true
        }else{
          //set your boolean variable to false
        }
      }

      public void onFinish() {}
    }.start();
```

Comment: I think yours is correct too since you use the 1 sec cooldown